# Organizing grafana dashboards using Kube-prometheus

Tags: grafana, prometheus-operator

I needed some help understanding how people are managing grafana dashboards using prometheus operator.

I have Prom operator running on my cluster. I have kube metrics dashboards through https://github.com/coreos/kube-prometheus. In this process, jsonnet generates the json files required and ksonnet gens the required kube artifacts aka configMaps.

Question is - I wanted to manage istio dashboards also similarly. Should i download the json files and integrate them into kube prometheus? If I did, how would I manage the updates if so? (https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/a671e62bd1ca3e6fd09bd0fbe03545c136b0f3f5/manifests/charts/istio-telemetry/grafana)